# Enums in computer memory

Tags: enums, language-agnostic

A quote from Wikipedia's article on [enumerated types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type) would be the best opening for this question:

> In other words, an enumerated type has values that are different from each other, and that can be compared and assigned, but which are **not specified** by the programmer **as having any particular concrete representation in the computer's memory**; compilers and interpreters can represent them arbitrarily.

While I understand the definition and uses of enums, I can't yet grasp the interaction between enums and memory — when an enum type is declared *without* creating an instance of enum type variable, is the type definition stored in memory as a union or a structure? And what is the meaning behind the aforementioned Wiki excerpt?

Comment: My perception of enums are that they only exist before compile time (in c, anyway). i.e. They are substituted for their integer value at compile time

Comment: The representation and implementation can be very different in different programming languages. As you ask about C, read about C `enum`s.

Comment: It's basically saying that if you have an enum variable, the compiler may choose any underlying basic type that suits its needs to represent it in memory.  Given `enum Xyz { ABC, DEF, GHI };`, a C programmer (and indeed programmers in general) have no control over the memory type used to store `enum Xyz` values.  In C, it could be `char` or `short` or `int` or some other type at the compiler's whim — unless there's an ABI (application binary interface) that defines what the compiler must do, of course.

Comment: And a **declaration** _never_ allocates memory. Do not confuse it with a _definition_

Comment: Without creating a variable, a value such as ABC may just be part of an assembler instruction, or it may be stored somewhere — probably in the text segment since its value won't change while the program runs.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Well, the constants in C have `int` type. In C++ and some other languages you can define the type for the `enum` type, too.

Comment: @Olaf: Yes, but it also says: _Each enumerated type shall be compatible with `char`, a signed integer type, or an unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined,_ with footnote 128 referenced which says _An implementation may delay the choice of which integer type until all enumeration constants have been seen._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: (I assume you talk about C) That does not contradict what I wrote about the _enum-constants_ actually. It just allows to use a smaller type for variables of that type, not the constants themselves. Btw. the implementation has to specify this behaviour, so in some aspects, the memory representation of the final type is well-specified, too.

Comment: No, but what you said about the constants doesn't contradict what I wrote, either.  So, we're talking in circles — let's cut the cackle.  (Anyway, I'm about to go into transit and won't be able to respond for some time.)

Comment: It's just that in C you often only use the constants, not the `enum` type itself (e.g. you don't even make it referenceable by omitting the tag and not `typedef`ing), if you need to use smaller types to store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wikipedia excerpt isn't talking specifically about C's `enum` types. The C standard has some specific requirements for how `enum`s work.

An enumerated type is compatible with either `char` or some signed or unsigned integer type. The choice of representation is up to the compiler, which must document its choice (it's *implementation-defined*), but the type must be able to represent all the values of the enumeration.

The values of the enumeration constants start at `0` by default, and increment by `1` for each successive constant:

```
enum foo {
    zero, // equal to 0
    one,  // equal to 1
    two   // equal to 2
};
```

The constants are always of type `int`, regardless of what the `enum` type itself is compatible with. (It would have made more sense for the constants to be of the enumerated type; they're of type `int` for historical reason.)

You can specify values for some or all of the constants -- which means that the values are not necessarily distinct:

```
enum bar {
    two = 2,
    deux = 2,
    zwei = 2,
    one = 1,
    dos  // implicitly equal to 2
};
```

Defining an enumerated type doesn't result in anything being stored in memory at run time. If you define an object of the enumerated type, that object's value will be stored in memory (unless it's optimized away), and will occupy `sizeof (enum whatever)` bytes. It's the same as for objects of any other type.

An enumeration constant is treated as a constant expression. The expression `two` is treated almost identically to a constant `2`.

Note that C++ has some different rules for `enum` types. Your question is tagged C, so I won't go into details.

Comment: Great answer - thank you! I got confused, however, at two places. First, you mentioned that an enum type is represented by a compiler as a 'char', 'uint' or else, depending on the settings of the compiler. There are less possible 'char' values than there are unsigned integers, so wouldn't it be more practical to just default 'enum' objects to 'uint' or does compiler do it automatically if 'chars' fill up? Second, if the enum constants were of 'enum' type themselves, does this mean that each of those constants is going to have a range of values that it can take as well? Just a smaller range?

Comment: @Agrus : I'm not sure what you  mean by `uint`; there is no such standard type. A `enum` type may have the same representation as `char`, as any signed integer type, or as any unsigned integer type. The compiler can make that choice in any way it likes.  As for enum constants, a constant has a single fixed value, not a range of values.

Comment: Perhaps `uint` is something more common to embedded systems programming. However, you are right, `uint` is not a standard type and perhaps it's used for simplicity purpose. If an `enum` is not assigned a value, then the compiler decides on its own what type to assign to it, be it a `char` or an `int`, right? And if the programmer doesn't specify the values, then they start from 0. So what happens if the number of defined enum constants is greater than the number of available `chars`? This is purely hypothetical as it seems like  enums are rather short.

Comment: @Agrus: `uint` is typically an alias (typedef) for `unsigned int`. I'd rather just write `unsigned int` so there's no ambiguity. But an `enum` type can be compatible with *any* signed or unsigned type, or with plain `char`; there's nothing special about `uint` or `unsigned int` in that context. The value of each enumeration constant is specified by the language, not by the compiler; it's the value specified, otherwise `0` for the first or the previous value + 1. The compiler chooses the underlying type, but that type must be able to represent the values of all the constants.

Comment: @Agrus: If some of the constants won't fit in a `char`, the compiler *must* choose a wider type.

Comment: @Agrus: For an example of how one compiler does this: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html (bottom of  the page).

Answer (score 1):

It means that the enum constants are not required to be located in memory. You cannot take the addresses of them.

This allows the compiler to replace all references to enum constants with their actual values. For example, the code:

```
enum { x = 123; }
int y = x;
```

may compile as if it were:

```
int y = 123;
```

> When an enum type is declared without creating an instance of enum type variable, is the type definition stored in memory as a union or a structure?

In C, types are mostly compile-time constructs; once the program has been compiled to machine code, all the type information disappears*. Accessing a struct member is instead "access the memory n bytes past this pointer".

So if the compiler inlines all the enums as shown above, then enums do not exist at all in compiled code.

* Except optionally in the debugging info section, but that's usually only read by debuggers.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Does this mean that if 'x' was declared as a variable before 'y' in the code, then assigning 'y' with the value of 'x' (i.e. y = x), takes the address of 'x' as it has been placed in memory, and copies whatever is at that address when this instruction is reached?